# Bootstrap 3 - Form horizontal not working

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-crispy-forms

I'm using `Django` with `CrispyForms` and I'm updating an old project of mine to `BS3`.

The only thing I didn't find out how to adapt are `form-horizontal`. My forms used to look like this:

[image]

Now the label is always on top of the input - like it was before with `form-vertical`.

I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018664/align-label-and-textbox-in-bs-3) some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404003/bootstrap-3-label-on-the-left-side-instead-above-a-input-field) on Stack, googled around but nobody has a working **crispy** answer for me!

The weirdest thing is that the Bootstrap guys [say that they did not change or remove](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration) this class.

Any ideas what I can do to get my old, lovely *horizontal*` forms back?

Thanks!

**Update:**

`CrispyForms` produces the following, even with `bootstrap3` as template pack:

```
<div class="form-group" id="div_id_title">
    <label class="control-label  requiredField" for="id_title">Titel
        <span class="asteriskField">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="controls ">
        <input type="text" name="title" maxlength="65" id="id_title" class="textinput textInput form-control"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look here:

http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#bootstrap3-horizontal-forms

You should add

```
helper.label_class = 'col-lg-x' #for example 'col-lg-2'
helper.field_class = 'col-lg-x' #for example 'col-lg-10'
```

BS3 has a 12 column grid system, more info about that here
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

That made the form horizontal but unfortunately the labels align to the left, I'm trying to fix that now.

UPDATE: If you have issues with the vertical spacing between the fields add a row css class to the outer div of every field, the html output:

```
<div class="form-group row" id="div_id_title">

    ###labels HTML###

</div>
```

Probably a bug on the field.html template for bootstrap3.

Answer (score 3):

Did you put the `form-control` inside `form-group`?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <label lass="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
</div>..
</form>
```

### Demo: http://bootply.com/104095

Comment: The problem seems to be that `CrispyForms` is not setting the classes right - even with 'bootstrap3' as template pack... I'll update my answer with an example

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. The label classes are getting set to "control-label requiredField"

Answer (score 3):

I spent a few hours trying to figure this out. For me, this worked. You have to go into the project settings.py and add the line:

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'
```

After searched thru the docs, I ended up find that I had to do this in the crispy-forms source code itself:

```
       if (
            TEMPLATE_PACK == 'bootstrap3'
            and not is_checkbox(field)
            and not is_file(field)
        ):
            css_class += ' form-control'
```